# Cannot generate SSPI context. Could this be a Windows Roles error

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I am getting unable to "Cannot generate SSPI context" error when my app is starting up in windows 2012.
User A who is the local admin is getting through to the database fine.  However user B who is normal user is getting this error.
My hunch is this has something to do with their AD profiles and the roles they are assigned to.   Any suggestions or out of the box suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Run: setspn -L <name of your SQL server> and paste the output here

Comment: This has nothing to do with AD profiles.